# advanced static polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Im building a network protocol and I want to use static polymorphism for my messages structures.
Some messages:

```
struct HelloConnectMessage {

    void serialize(BinaryWriter &writer) const {

    }

    void deserialize(BinaryReader &reader) {

    }

    std::ostream &dump(std::ostream &o) const {
        return o << "HelloConnectMessage()";
    }
};

struct TestMessage {
    boost::uint16_t foo;

    void serialize(BinaryWriter &writer) const {
        writer.writeUshort(foo);
    }

    void deserialize(BinaryReader &reader) {
        foo = reader.readUshort();
    }

    std::ostream &dump(std::ostream &o) const {
        return o << "TestMessage(foo=" << foo << ")";
    }
};
```

Each message got an unique identifier (id/opcode) and I would like to store them in a map and be able to instance them at runtime, knowing that they dont have any base class. So I was wondering if this is possible with static polymorphism.

I though about functors but I always got a problem when trying to declaring, I can't specify a type since they dont have any parent.

Maybe this could illustrate my problem:

```
using opcode = std::uint16;

std::unordered_map<opcode, ?generic_type?> _protocol;
```

I think I could replace ?generic_type? by a class template but it's complicated since I can't put a template on a class member variable. I also though about a factory but I still have the problem of a base type.

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<?generic_type?> messageFactory() {
    return std::make_unique<T>();
}

std::unordered_map<opcode, std::unique_ptr<?generic_type?>(*)()> _protocol;
_protocol[1] = messageFactory<HelloConnectMessage>(); // example
```

Is this finally possible to do what I'm looking for without parent class?

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want runtime-dependent static polymorphism? This is a bit of a contradiction. Why can't you use runtime polymorphism and virtual functions?

Comment: why cannot you use x-macros for that?

Comment: @alterigel nice question, i just wanna try new things, I already did it with virtual inheritance, but I found my code with too much verbosity

Comment: @John could u explain more about that?

Comment: It's definitely possible if you use things like templates and lambdas and type erasure, but I think good ol' OOP would be by far the prettiest, given how your `HelloConnectMessage` and `TestMessage` are structured.

Comment: If you want elegant, self-explanatory and correct code, I would strongly urge against the use of macros.

Comment: each message simply got 3 functions, serialize/deserialize and dump. Only differencies between messages will be the serialization rules

Comment: well, so it seems I cant do it without virtual inheritance

Comment: I could give examples but your problem lends itself perfectly to runtime polymorphism and I don't understand the need. What's so verbose about a single `Message` base class with 3 virtual functions, and `override`ing its functions in your concrete message types? Your `?generic?` type then merely becomes `Message`.

Comment: Why don't you follow C++ conventions and use `<<` and `>>` to read and write from your serialized object?

Comment: This is exactly what im trying to avoid, qualifications override or virtual. I want simple structures and light

Comment: is `_protocol` going to be used as a constant map solely for instantiation given some opcode?

Comment: @tadman because I found more readable to explicity write "WriteUshort" meaning write an unsigned int on 16 bits

Comment: You could do it with `std::function`s and lambdas and so forth. But it won't be as simple or maintainable as virtual inheritance, and you'll use a lot of strongly-typed safety.

Comment: @John yes it will

Comment: Let the types do the talking for you. C++ function overrides can be exceedingly specific, meaning you can handle them on a case-by-case basis. The WriteUshort type functions are what Java or C would do.

Comment: @tadman so you would prefer to `stream << (uint16) 18;` ?

Comment: That's an approach that makes it fairly clear what your intent is, but it really depends on how often you're doing something that low-level. Normally you read and write at a higher level of abstraction, like passing in a message or receiving one, with the fields already populated correctly.

Comment: @Romeortec [Here's explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) what's usually meant with the term _static polymorphism_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would say the CRTP is a special case. Static polymorphism is often as simple as expecting some parameterized `typename T` to have members `begin()` and `end()`

Comment: Only way I found is to use a C++ 17 Variant for store all my structures